# Fix broken basketball pole

Tags: repair, outdoor, metal, play-structures, pole

I have this basketball from previous owner of the house and it's concreted to the ground. Now after many years (I assume), it's rusted and broken on top.

I am wondering what is the best way to connect the two pieces without replacing it:

[image]
[image]

Is there some metal bracket that I can wrap around and bolt into both pieces?

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a number of choices:

1. Remove the whole top half of the pole by separating at this joint and replacing that top half. You would drill new holes and mount the backboard brackets to the new pipe section.

[image]

2. Find another piece of pipe that just slides inside of the two pieces. Secure in place using new drilled through holes and bolts. You already have to deal with this as the rust off break is at the lower cross bolt for the backboard bracket. This slide in pipe would want to be a pretty close fit and would want to be a good 2.5 to 3 feet in length.
3. It would be a bit more work to secure and attach but you could also acquire two pieces of 2" angle iron that were the similar 2.5 to 3 feet in length. Lay these up along the sides of the existing tubing and secure in place using large size band gear clamps all the way around the outside of both angle irons.

[image]

Comment: Option 2 would be ideal and seem easiest. Can I use two half-pipes and "wrap" from the outside and drill bolts through? I mean cosmetically inside is better but I am just not sure if there is a piece that fit perfectly inside.

Comment: Option 1 would be easiest if you can contact the manufacturer and simply get a replacement top half tube. Option 2 is easy if you can find the material at a decent price. Measure your ID and then look for tubing with slightly smaller OD. Check at local muffler shops for tubing or online at McMasterCarr. Option 3 you should be able to find all parts at a big box store like Home Depot. Make sure with that one to use at least 6 of the gear clamps.

Comment: Option 3 is to ditch the whole project and use the basketball net in the background of the picture haha

Answer (score 2):

Buy a piece of exhaust pipe in same diameter. Preferably 12 inches long.. Split the pipe lengthwise. Slip it over broken pole ends, Clamp it in place with exhaust clamps and put a band clamp over the break area. Make sure the pole is level vertically before tightening all clamps. About $ 45 in parts.